# assign values to form inputs without Javascript or HTML, just like outlook.com is doing

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you see outlook.com, there is an input box, with a default value inside it which says "Email, phone or Skype" in gray color. Once you start typing in that input box, this default value disappears, and if you delete all your text inside the input box, the default prompt will appear again. This is a great way to minimize the text on my website to avoid a separate label for every input box of every form.

Now, you might think this was done by Javascript, but it isn't. If you disable your browser's Javascript the outlook.com page will still show the same behavior.

My question is how can I do something like that? ie show a default value on my input boxes, and then hide/remove it once the use actually starts typing in those boxes, and all without Javascript. I know it must be possible, just as outlook.com has done. But how?

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Labels_and_placeholders#The_placeholder_attribute

Comment: This is called a placeholder text. It's done by adding a `placeholder` attribute to the HTML element. It's therefore done by HTML and you cannot really be done without it. *Maybe* there is some CSS black magic that can accomplish it but I'm not aware of any that does it reliably - I've seen some hacks using the `::before` pseudo-classes to do something like that but it doesn't in all circumstances and is usually way more of a hassle.

Comment: @vlaz You can imitate a similar behaviour using javascript too. A good example of this would be facebook's DraftJS - they use a custom placeholder over a `contenteditable`div. Everything's possible. Great explanation about placeholder tho!

Comment: @SivcanSingh I know you can do it via JS. In fact, since `placeholder` is an HTML5 attribute, you *have* to use JS, if you want to backport it to older browsers like IE8. I was focusing on the (somewhat bizarre) requirement by OP to be done without using HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your HTML code and see the magic of `placeholder`

```css
#magic {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
   <input placeholder="Make this invisible on typing" id="magic"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Labels_and_placeholders#The_placeholder_attribute

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much @Sivcan Singh You saved me!